# Why did Symfony forms does not using validator normally?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have the collection model:

```
class EntityList {
    /**
     * @var Entity[]
     * @Assert\Count(min=1)
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $entityList;

    // ...
}
```

The single model:

```
class Entity {
    /**
     * @var int
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $name;

    // ...
}
```

The collection's form:

```
class EntityListType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('entity', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => EntityType::class, 
            'allow_add' => true,
            'property_path' => 'entityList',
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefault('data_class', EntityList::class);
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix() { 
        return null; 
    }
}
```

And the entity's form:

```
class EntityType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('id', NumberType::class)
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefault('data_class', Entity::class);
    }
}
```

The collection's form using in a controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(EntityListType::class);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

I send the package with no required title (it's an API):

```
curl -X POST ... 
    -d entity[0][id]=10
```

And that accept it! The method `isValid` returns `true`. But if form's data check manually with `ValidationComponent` as:

```
if ($form->isValid()) { // it's valid, okay
    echo $this->get('validator')->validate($form->getData()); // it's still not valid!
}
```

I see correct errors ('title is required')! Why?

P.S. Symfony 3.2, stable.

P.P.S. I was found temporarily solution now. It's use `$form->submit($request->request->all());` instead of `$form->handleRequest($request);`. But I don't understand this feature.